# divided powers of a deformation class

Tags: deformation-theory, hochschild-cohomology, associative-algebras, divided-powers

Let $A$ be a (unital, associative) $k$-algebra where $k$ is a field. Given a flat deformation of $A$ one gets the deformation class $h$ in the second Hochschild cohomology $HH^2(A)$. Suppose $k$ has positive characteristic and $h$ happens to come with divided powers $h^{[p^n]}$. Does that indicate any additional structure on the deformation, something that would naturally induce such a divided power structure?

Comment: This answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/353643 suggests that you should ask these guys https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.07352

Comment: If $p$ is odd, then the restricted operation $-^{[p]}$ on Hochschild cohomology is only defined on odd-degree classes. So I am not sure of the meaning of $h^{[p^n]}$.